# ObjectMapper readerForUpdating to replace array

Tags: java, jackson

I have two different JSON files.

File A:

```json
{
    "label": "A",
    "links": [
        {
            "url": "urla"
        }
    ]
}
```

File B:

```json
{
    "links": [
        {
            "url": "urlb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update A with the contents of B to get the following result JSON:

```json
{
    "label": "A",
    "links": [
        {
            "url": "urlb"
        }
    ]
}
```

That is the `links` array should be fully replaced with the contents of B.
But instead it merges the two Arrays:

```json
{
    "label": "A",
    "links": [
        {
            "url": "urla",
            "url": "urlb"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is not desired.
The code for the merged file:

```java
JsonNode A = ... // resolved from a service call
JsonNode B = ... // resolved from a service call
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
result = mapper.readerForUpdating(A).readValue(B);
```

I also tried to set `mapper.setDefaultMergeable(false);` but it didn't help.

I use `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8`

Can someone help me?

Comment: You don't say what version of Jackson you're using but this may offer some insight: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1625

Comment: Good hint, its com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8

Comment: From the discussion at that issue it sounds like it should work as you expect right out of the box.  We don't use that method in our Jackson-heavy project so I can't offer concrete advice, sorry.  I wasn't aware of the method you're using which is why I looked into (yet can't give you an answer).  If you figure it out please answer your own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this can help:
`mapper.configOverride(ArrayNode.class).setMergeable(false)`